# Visual Studio: Trigger post build step after post build step failure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, post-build-event

I have configured some post build step in project. Post build step is performing copying of produced binaries to some external folders.

In Visual studio 2010 project if post build step fails, next time I try to build project again, vs will retry post build step automatically. Works as expected.

In Visual studio 2015 project if post build step fails, next time I try to build project again, vs will claim that project is up-to-date.

Is this some Visual studio bug or expected behavior ?

Comment: increasing `Tools->Options->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity` might help you figure out why the post-build isn't running.

Comment: If I just want the post-build event - I use "Project Only" / "Link project" - it re-runs the project link step and then executes post-build

Comment: @TarmoPikaro, I agree with MuertoExcobito. Visual Studio claim that project is up-to-date, which means VS not run any target include post build event, otherwise, VS should throw the build error again. So you should check the post build command line. If this issue persist, you can share your command line in the build event, I will check it for you.

Comment: I'm copying file with xcopy, and it causes sharing violation if application is active - bit annoying that vs does not retry automatically.